# How to constraint a view to be bigger than UIWindow?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, frame

I need to have a scene in my project which is bigger than UIWindow.
It's an app which work on multiple devices at the same time.
If 3 devices are connected the frame width should make 3x the size of a device.

Then each devices frame's origin are set differently to see different parts of the scene.

I can do it with Auto-layout off, but I need this for useful reasons. The fact is I tried a lot of things and none worked, Storyboard always override what I set programmatically.

Is it possible to set a constraint width/height in interface builder for the superview ? How you would do otherwise to make a view bigger than window but working with autolayout ?

Answer (score 0):

In general **from IB you can't set constraints for your mainView related to its superview**, because IB **doesn't known where you will attach that view** and so which will be its superview then, therefore it couldn't double check if your constraints are valid or not.

You can still insert any constraints by code.

Comment: When I add it by code it's doesn't update subview or childController views.

Comment: Is use a mainController with a containerController to present differents multiscreen viewController. All of these childs controller are made in interface builder. I want to set the size of the mainController view and then replicate in subview but still doesn't make it